# TIdHttpServer freezing; calls to "OnCommandGet" start but never finish

Tags: delphi, indy

I have a Delphi 2007 **TNtService** based web service utilizing the Indy **TIdHttpServer** component.  The server works fine and can be quite stable for hours.  But every so often (usually 3-6 hours), it freezes.

Based on logging I have built into the service, **OnCommandGet** calls are being started but not completed.  I have threadsafe counter variables at the beginning and end of the **OnCommandGet** handler.  And can see when the freezing starts the "start" variable increments while the "end" count remains the same.

I let the server remain in a state like this for a couple minutes.  Sometimes everything "gets back to normal", and all threads complete (although taking many minutes).  If it goes more than a couple minutes I have the service **Halt** itself.  I then have another auxiliary service to restart it.

Some of my OnCommandGet handlers spawn **TThread** threads.  Originally I was not setting the **priority**, instead taking the default value.  I was able to correlate the freezing to times when these threads were working.  Afterwards I set **priority := tpLowest;**, and this seemed to mitigate the problem somewhat.

But I still get freezing and have no idea what it is.

Could it be something else in Windows consuming resources?  (I have checked **eventvwr** logs and don't see anything).

Is there some way I can detect which threads/contexts are using all the memory?

Below is the code I am using to create the server.  Not sure that it will help, as the server seems to work fine on startup.

**Update 1**
@jerrydodge and @remylebeau pointed out code within the **OnCommandGet** needs to be included.  Problem with this: there are a lot of **if...then..else** cases and calls to other functions.  I have functions to return **js** and **css** files, and there are about 50 calls to other handler procedures.  Not sure that it would provide much.   I really think if anything it might be something within one of these calls.  I guess the approach might be is to try and find out which handler is the culprit.  And part of my writing this question was possibly to be given suggestions on how you can see which processes are consuming resources.  Is there a way to get CPU of specific Contexts?

```
ServerIOHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(self);
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'C:\web\vaut\embeddedanalytics.com.crt';
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'C:\web\vaut\embeddedanalyticsout.key';
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'C:\web\vaut\gd_bundle.crt';
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer;


IdHTTPServer1 := TIdHTTPServer.Create;
IdHTTPServer1.MaxConnections := FMaxConnections;
IdHTTPServer1.AutoStartSession := True;
IdHTTPServer1.KeepAlive := FGlobalKeepAlive;
IdHTTPServer1.SessionState := True;
IdHTTPServer1.OnCommandGet := MainGet;
IdHTTPServer1.onexception := IdHttpServerexception;
IdHTTPServer1.onlistenexception := IdHttpServerlistenexception;
with idHttpServer1 do begin
  onconnect := IdHttpServerConnect;
  oncreatesession := IdHttpServerCreateSession;
  ondisconnect := IdHttpServerDisconnect;
  onsessionend := IdHttpServersessionend;
  onsessionstart := IdHttpServersessoinstart;
end;
idHttpServer1.ParseParams := True;

try
  CoInitialize(nil);
  // Connect to database...  Do other initialization stuff
finally
  CoUninitialize;
end;
idHttpServer1.OnQuerySSLPort := QuerySSLPort;
idHttpServer1.IOHandler := ServerIOHandler;
idHttpServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := FPort;
idHttpServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 443;
IdHTTPServer1.Active := True;
```

**UPDATE 2**
I have a procedure in my code which reports the current memory usage using the function below.  I know this could be a separate question itself.  But is **GetProcessMemoryInfo** threadsafe?  Because I am NOT wrapping it in Critical Section.

```
function CurrentMemoryUsage: Cardinal;
var
 pmc: TProcessMemoryCounters;
begin
 pmc.cb := SizeOf(pmc) ;
 result := 0;
 if GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess, @pmc, SizeOf(pmc)) then
   Result := pmc.WorkingSetSize
 else
   RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: `IdHTTPServer1 := TIdHTTPServer.Create;` doesn't seem right to me. Are you creating multiple instances of a component which is already created on your service module? It seems the problem however is not in your code above, but in the code which we cannot see. Chances are, one of your threads is doing something not-so-thread-safe.

Comment: Agreed. You say your `OnCommandGet` code is freezing, but you did not show the actual code for it.

Comment: @JerryDodge and Remy  See **Update1**.  Difficult to provide this.  But I will see about generalizing it.

Comment: When it freezes, break in with a debugger and find out where it's frozen.

Comment: For services, you can use a remote debugger.

Comment: @JerryDodge - Ok - will need to learn more about remote debugger.  Per what Rob Kennedy said, I was going to redirect my website to a development machine and run the service directly within Delphi 2007.

Comment: @RobKennedy - See Update2.....  Basically is GetProcessMemoryInfo thread safe?

Comment: Why do you ask? Were all your threads stuck calling GetProcessMemoryInfo when you suspended your program in the debugger?

Comment: @RobKennedy - No.  I still haven't used the debugger.  But in looking at my own logs when the freezing starts (basically a list of all context's ARequestInfo.document), I noticed one was a call that was in turn calling GetprocessmemoryInfo.  Should GetprocessmemoryInfo be wrapped if called in "oncommandGet"??

Comment: That function is *probably* not the source of the problem. But don't settle for "probably" when you can get "certainly" by using a debugger.

Comment: @RobKennedy: or simply adding some extra logging before and after the `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` calls to make sure they are all exiting.